# "BOOTMANAGER is missing" error when trying to dual boot

Tags: dual-boot

Trying to use 11.10 boot manager to load windows 7. I get the message that BOOTMANAGER is missing (for win 7 i suppose). 
both os on same sda: U on sda7, win on sda2. win was installed first, then U was added. 
I can see the win7 load line while booting, but immediately after choosing win7 i get the message of non bootmngr for the win area.

How do I add bootmanager so can win 7 can b used? I have the correct sda2 uuid of cause.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an and windows 7 disk handy. Boot off of it and choose recovery. Then choose recovery console and type fixmbr, this should get the windows boot screen back and also have a choice for ubuntu if it's still intsalled.

Comment: hmm... tnx.. nore ("dos") prompt ("path") neither myself could find fixmbr. where exactly should it be run from?